# Prevent notifications from being dismissed when clicked?

Tags: kde, xfce, browser, notifications, user-interface

On all the desktop environments I've used, clicking a browser notification makes it disappear. Is there some way to prevent this behavior to make it more in line with Windows/macOS where clicking a notification does not dismiss it?

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out the app "Recent Notifications", people use it for that purpose, there are some old posts about it here:
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history)
and [here](https://itsfoss.com/notifications-appindicator/)
I believe thats what your looking for and it appears still under active development.
If not you'd have to tell us more about your system and window manager KDE / Gnome /  or?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's an archive of past notifications. I'm talking about the actual notifications that appear on screen via a browser, like Chrome. I want clicking them to not result in them disappearing, and then me needing to dig them up from _Recent Notifications_.

Comment: Tell us more about your OS and what window manager you use.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned in the body text rather than just the tags, this affects KDE/Xfce - on all Debian-based distros I've tried. I don't know if the issue would affect non-Debian distros, but I suspect yes. PS: I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Ahh OK thanks, well it should be a solvable QT / KDE / plasma configuration thing. I run openbox with tint2 and tinynotify-send and I have the history in my dock/panel.